# Compiler cannot resolve classes in io.ktor.client.features.logging

Tags: android, gradle, logging, kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to add logging for `Ktor` http requests in Android application. According to [docs](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/features/logging.html) I have to add gradle dependency

`implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"`

and just use this snippet

```
val client = HttpClient() {
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.DEFAULT
        level = LogLevel.HEADERS
    }
}
```

Problem is that compiler "ignores" package 'io.ktor.client.features.logging' added as a dependency. What's strange is that JsonFeature (added as similar dependency) works just fine.

```
install(JsonFeature) { // perfectly works
...
}

install(Logging) { // unresolved reference
...
}
```

I already checked `.jar` file that gradle added to the project, it contains all expected classes, I can open them and see the source code, but magically just can't use in my app. After hours of research I guess it may be somehow related to gradle metadata or that logging feature is multiplatform and some additional gradle configuration is required, but unfortunately I'm not a gradle expert.

I tried adding `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` to `settings.gradle`, but no effect. Even tried to add "-jvm" to dependency.

`implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor_version"`

With this dependency Android Studio finding package successfully, but fails to compile with following error

`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/ktor-http.kotlin_module'`

Can anyone please clarify how to properly configure dependency for Ktor logger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the `ktor-client-logging` you have to have the dependency set for each platform:

```
commonMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"
    }
}

androidMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor_version"
    }
}

iosMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktor_version"
    }
}
```

as for the meta `META-INF/ktor-http.kotlin_module` add to the `app/build.gradle` inside the `android {}` block:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the setup correcty but I dont see any logs. Can you guide me here?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones are you by any chance initializing HttpClient with `HttpClient { install(Logging) { logger = Logger.DEFAULT } }` and perhaps `level = LogLevel.ALL` without more information I'm afraid I won't be able to help.

Comment: Yes I did. I am trying to see the logs in Android but could not see any. Do you have a project that works which I look at?

Comment: `io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm` assumes you have SL4J as a dependency. Add it as a dependency and you will see the logs.

Comment: Thanks for adding to the answer @Emmanuel I thought the client already included SL4J -> https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/master/ktor-client/ktor-client-features/ktor-client-logging/build.gradle.kts

Comment: I thought it did too, but as we can see it is a compile only dependency.

Comment: Good catch on that @Emmanuel as per [Logging in Ktor](https://ktor.io/servers/logging.html) documentation `logback` which is the successor of log4j is mentioned and included in `commonMain` and thus should cover the case of the missing dependency for `SL4J`.