# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-coroutines

In an Android project. I use

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.0"
```

and I run into

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'’

and even

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module'
}
```

doesn't work

Comment: why these dependencies don't list `atomicfu`?

Comment: This may help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484636/974184 look for the `packagingOptions` block.

Answer (score 4):

I made it work with

```
android {

    ...

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/kotlinx-io.kotlin_module'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-io.kotlin_module'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer might actually be more simple than working around home-made problems.

just see the dependencies of [atomicfu](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/atomicfu); it pulls in these:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.30
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.30
```

which that Java 7 module might duplicate:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I got this error (*More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/kotlinx-io.kotlin_module'*) for `**Koin**`!

should remove Extra dependencies, that mean :

**In the past (When I toke this error):**

```
  def koin_version = '2.0.1'
// Koin AndroidX Scope features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
// Koin AndroidX ViewModel features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
// Koin AndroidX Experimental features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-ext:$koin_version"

    // Koin for Ktor Kotlin
    implementation "org.koin:koin-ktor:$koin_version"
```

**New (Fixed with it ) :**

```
    def koin_version = '2.0.1'
// Koin AndroidX Scope features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
// Koin AndroidX ViewModel features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

Even i was facing same issue, fixed by adding these line to packagingOptions to build.gradle file

```
packagingOptions {
   pickFirst'META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module'
}
```

Comment: link full file please, which buid.gradle file

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped me in multiple projects!