# How to use Log in kotlin multiplatform Moblie

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am working in Ktor. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484636/18958467) to show log in specific platform iOS and Android. But when I am building this through gradle I am getting error on this when running this command on terminal. Normal build is successfully without any error, but getting error when I used below command.

```
./gradlew build --warning-mode all
```

**Error**

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule:compileIosMainKotlinMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule:allSourceSetsCompileDependenciesMetadata'.
   > Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule
      > Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:2.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release/io/ktor/ktor-client-logging-native/2.0.1/ktor-client-logging-native-2.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release/io/ktor/ktor-client-logging-native/2.0.1/ktor-client-logging-native-2.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:2.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://mobile-sdk.jumio.com/io/ktor/ktor-client-logging-native/2.0.1/ktor-client-logging-native-2.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://mobile-sdk.jumio.com/io/ktor/ktor-client-logging-native/2.0.1/ktor-client-logging-native-2.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "13.0"
        framework {
            baseName = "kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val ktorVersion = "2.0.1"
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.3.2")
                implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.0-beta-1")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
```

Can someone know how can I use log in iOS/darwin side. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you check for the [ktor-client-logging-native artifact on the Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ktor/ktor-client-logging-native) you'll find that the latest version is 1.3.1.

So they likely dropped the artifact under that name from v2. If you search for `ktor-client-logging` similarly, you'll find artifacts with `-iosx64`, `-iosarm64` architectures that have a `v2.0.1`.

I couldn't find a proper Ktor documentation, but I believe that if you only add the `io.ktor:ktor-client-logging` dependency in `commonMain` it will figure out which platform specific dependency to pull in.

**TL;DR**

You can remove both

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktorVersion")
```

and

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-native:$ktorVersion")
```

As they will be pulled in automatically by specifying the `commonMain` dependency

```
val commonMain by getting {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
}
```

Comment: #RobertNagy If I used in common. The log is not printing in console

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like `Napier` KMM library in order to make use of the `ktor-client-logging` dependency. You can find Napier on GitHub from this link:

https://github.com/AAkira/Napier

Here's an official JetBrains YouTube video on how to implement Napier to log Ktor stuff...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Q62iJoNOfg

Answer (score 0):

Leave the Ktor logging library in `commonMain`, and remove it in any other source sets. The right implementation for each platform will be brought in automatically.

```kotlin
val commonMain by getting {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version")
}
```

Also, since you're using a private maven repository, make sure the artifacts are actually there.

As for logging for Android / JVM, it doesn't work out of the box, unless you add a dependency on an SLF4J implementation, per the docs: https://ktor.io/docs/client-logging.html#add_dependencies

If you'd rather not bring in the dependency, you can just implement a simple logger:

```kotlin
class DebugKtorLogger : Logger {
    override fun log(message: String) {
        Log.v("Ktor", message)
    }
}
```

and install it:

```kotlin
val client = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    install(Logging) {
        logger = DebugKtorLogger()
        level = BODY
    }
}
```

Comment: If I used in common. The log is not printing in console.

Comment: Edited, added some more gotchas. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting logs to show up in the logcat for my multiplatform app even after setting up the Ktor client. The fix for me was changing the logger from `Logger.Default` to `Logger.SIMPLE`.

Here's what I did:

1. Add the Ktor client logging dependency in your `commonMain` module:

   ```kotlin
   commonMain.dependencies {
       implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor")
   }
   ```
2. Update the logging setup:

   ```kotlin
   install(Logging) {
       logger = Logger.SIMPLE
       level = LogLevel.ALL
   }
   ```

After making these changes, my logs started showing up in the logcat.